# Delete Built-in Administrator

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-scripting

Back story real quick: some reason some servers have 2 local admin account... no idea, I took over the job and cleaning everything up.

I need to go through 600-ish (or more) servers to delete the extra account.

PowerShell is great but can't work this out. How can I modify and read this location in PowerShell?

I can read up to here: HKLM:\SAM, and cannot see HKLM:\SAM\SAM... ?
How can I get PowerShell to edit permissions and read this location?

Once I can see this location I will work out how to delete it `remove-item-somethingsomething`

Thanks all :)

Comment: is the powershell run as admin? btw, i think its better to try to ask on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), i'm not sure if this kind question belongs to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) though as its not exactly "general computer question."

Comment: thanks dude, i can copy it to ServerFault......... and yup its running as Administrator (right click run as administrator)

Comment: You can simply use "Get-LocalUser" to enum users and "Remove-LocalUser" to delete them, remember don't delete the wrong user, trouble will come if you do.

Comment: Will this delete the 'built-in' local administrator account ?